# Error occurred while attempting to decode the Jwt.The ID Token contains invalid claims

Tags: spring-boot, azure-active-directory, jwt, spring-oauth2

I am adding oauth into an application(Java based) and I'm running into the following error:
[image]

`[invalid_id_token] An error occurred while attempting to decode the Jwt: The ID Token contains invalid claims`

I have followed all the steps to setup Azure AD and java project using the offical documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/developer/java/spring-framework/configure-spring-boot-starter-java-app-with-azure-active-directory
I checked the validity of my token using Postman- it's working there.

I'm stuck since 2 days. Tried many things but nothing worked. Anyone please help

Comment: Please  provide the token claims after decoding , by masking confidential details. Is aud value and client id same?

Comment: `{ "typ": "JWT", "alg": "RS256", "kid": "jS1Xo1OWDj_52vb******2VzMc" }.{ "aud": "46fbdb31-c7f****-8937-85****", "iss": "https://login.microsoftonline.com/344728-88******/v2.0", "iat": 1654620025, "nbf": 1654***25, "exp": 1654623925, "aio": "E2ZgYEiLK*****xAQA=", "azp": "46fbdb3*****5-8937-85e20184914f", "azpacr": "1", "oid": "b3061a****14a-8f50-076a64", "rh": "0.AVU****IgLuF5oOAT***F4gGEkU-IAAA.", "roles": [ "Admin" ], "sub": "b3061acc-cf3****b3d464", "tid": "3447da78-008a-4e28****804d", "uti": "yZ1****S2vAA", "ver": "2.0" }.[Signature]`

Comment: yes, aud value and client id are same.

Comment: What is the value of accessTokenAcceptedVersion in the manifest  in azure portal

Comment: @kavyasaraboju-MT: value is 2

Comment: it is correct to have 2 as iss is 2 . But i can see that aud value shown in the error is different from the one shown  in decoded claim

Comment: aud value is same in both error and decoded claims. I had masked the aud value while sharing that's why you found them different

Answer (score 2):

As your error : `An error occurred while attempting to decode the Jwt: The ID Token contains invalid claims :- {aud`  ,it says invalid claim is aud i.e; audience value .

***The ID Token MUST be rejected if the ID Token does not list the Client as a ***`valid audience`, or `if it contains additional audiences not trusted` by the Client.******

According to [aud -Pay load claims in  Microsoft identity platform ID tokens - Microsoft Entra | Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/id-tokens#payload-claims)

> Aud, Identifies the intended recipient of the token. In id_tokens, the
> audience is your app's Application ID i.e.; clientId, assigned to your app in the
> Azure portal. This value should be validated. The tokenis
> rejected if it fails to match your app's Application ID.

Also  please make sure that server running your spring boot app has the correct time.

Comment: So, what should I modify? 
Also, server running your spring boot app has the correct time? Sorry I did't get this?